# Should we use or not constant type reference in arguments of a function?

Tags: c++, memory, reference

#### Example 1.

```cpp
void f(int a);
```

#### Example 2 (constant type reference).

```cpp
void f(const int& a);
```

Is it better to use the second example because we don't create a copy of an argument object within a function? But why in most cases, even companies, use exactly the first example? I know about big objects - via the second example we can save some memory. I'm asking about ordinary types in c++.

Comment: I know the difference, but why I always see that everyone uses `void f(int a)` case if even they don't change the `a` argument?

Comment: For simple types creating reference is heavier operation than creating copy, So for double, int and some other simple types it is better to use copy rather than const reference

Comment: Depending on what's in your function, access by refernce can be less cache coherent than access by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, a reference passed as function argument will be a pointer, it‘s just some syntactic sugar which makes the reference a bit different to handle compared to a pointer.

Memory wise, the size of an `int` is 32 bit on most common platforms. The size of a pointer (and thus also the size of a reference passed as argument) is 64 bit on a 64 bit platform and 32 bit on a 32 bit platform.

So passing a reference to a POD might even involve more data being copied compared to passing a copy. So there is no performance gain to expect passing an int by const reference instead of by value. And the function signature looks slightly better readable